# Preload MediaPlayer in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an RecylcerView with multiple imges in my app.
If the images are getting loaded in the onBindViewholder it should also prepare the MediaPlayer.
When the user clicks the button it should start the MediaPlayer.
Normaly I would just create the MediaPlayer when the user clicks the button but in my case I'm playing the sound from an URL so it takes some time for the sound to play when the user has bad internet.
So I try to create and prepare the MediaPlayer as soon as the RecyclerView Item gets created and start it when the user clicks the button.

Is this the right way to do it? Because now I have the problem that I have multiple MediaPlayers at once and I don't know how I can stop and clear all MediaPlayers when the user clicks a "stop" button.

Here is the onBindViewHolder method from my RecyclerView Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SoundViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SoundItems currentItem = mSoundItems.get(position);
  
    final String imageUrl = currentItem.getImageResource(); 
    final String mp3Path = currentItem.getMp3Path();
 
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
            .into(holder.itemImageView);
 
 
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3Path);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    holder.itemImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { 
 
            mediaPlayer.start();
 


        }
    });
```

What is the best way to preload the sounds so that the sound gets played instantly when the user clicks button and how to stop all MediaPlayers at once?
P.S
The sounds are between 3 and 30 seconds long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code :

Instead of using Exoplayer you can use MediaPlayer if you want..
But with this code files will be prefetched too.

https://github.com/NehaKushwah993/InstagramVideoFeedClone

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, sadly I'm not good at Kotlin so I cannot really use your code.
Thanks anyways